# Js RegExp Проверка на числа и некотрые символы

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно вернуть `true` , если вводимое значение содержит любые цифры, а так же точку или запятую, или двоеточие. 
Пробовал так, но работает некорректно:

```
val.match(/^[0-9]|\.|,|:*$/)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, для проверки совпадения в строке можно воспользоваться соответствующим методом `RegExp#test()`, который возвращает `true` (если совпадение найдено) или `false` (если совпадение не найдено).

Выражение `^[0-9]|\.|,|:*$` вернёт `true`, если строка начинается с цифры (`^[0-9]`), содержит `.` или `,`  (`\.|,`) или заканчивается на 0 и более знаков `:` (`:*$`). Из-за `:*$` совпадение будет найдено в любой строке, так как в любой строке есть конец строки.

Вам нужно одно из двух выражений:

- Если в строке *помимо любых других символов* есть цифра, точка, запятая или двоеточие - `if (/[\d.,:]/.test(str)) { return true; }`
- Если в строке могут быть *только* цифры, точки, запятые или двоеточия - `if (/^[\d.,:]*$/.test(str)) { return true; }` или - если строка не может быть пустой - `if (/^[\d.,:]+$/.test(str)) { return true; }`

Answer (score 1):

Правильно будет так: `/[0-9\\.,:]/`

точку нужно экранировать.

Без экранирования точка соответствует любому символу, кроме `\n` и `\r`.

Comment: судя по всему, это комментарий к [другому ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1003120/178576). чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Вот и всё выражение должно быть: `/[0-9.,:]/`.

Answer (score 0):

А вот функция для проверки только на числовое значение (без скобки и двоеточия)

```
is_numeric  = function (object) {
    if(typeof object == 'number') return true;
    else if(typeof object == 'string') {
        if(object.match(/[^\d\.EXABCDEF\-\+]/gi) || isNaN(parseFloat(object))) return false;
        try {if(!isNaN(eval(object))) return true} catch(e) {return false}
    }
}
```

Comment: стоило дополнить свой предыдущий ответ вместо написания нового.